# Deployment methods for docker based micro services architecture on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, microservices, amazon-ecs

I am working on a project using a microservices architecture.
Each service lives in its own docker container and has a separate git repository in order to ensure loose coupling.

It is my understanding that AWS recently announced support for [Multi-Container Docker environments in ElasticBeanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html). This is great for development because I can launch all services with a single command and test everything locally on my laptop. Just like Docker Compose.

However, it seems I only have the option to also deploy all services at once which I am afraid defies the initial purpose of having a micro services architecture.

I would like to be able to deploy/version each service independently to AWS. What would be the best way to achieve that while keeping infrastructure management to a minimum?

Comment: You need to have some sort of manageent application. I would recommend you to look at ansible, chef  and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently using [Amazon ECS](http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) to accomplish exactly what you are talking about trying to achieve.  You can define your Docker Container as a Task definition and then Create an ECS Service which will handle number of instances, scaling, etc.

One thing to note is Amazon mentions the word container a lot in the documentation.  They may be talking about the EC2 instance used for the cluster for your docker instances/containers.